# Transition on hover, except if hovering over a certain element

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

I have an element that looks something like this:

```
 ___
|  X|
 ‾‾‾
```

So essentially a tiny box with a button to close it.

I have also applied CSS to the element, so that when hovered, it will turn to something like this:

```
 ___________________
|                  X|
 ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
```

Simply put, it'll just become wider.

Now. what I want to do is that whenever the user hovers over the close button (X), the box will not change its size.
But when the user hovers on anywhere else on the box, it would behave as suggested.

Is this possible with pure CSS?

EDIT: Sorry that I added this late, but the answers should be based around this example: http://jsfiddle.net/fpY34

Comment: CAn we see your code please?

Comment: That's pretty much impossible, but it's essentially just a bunch of nested divs. I might be able to create a JSFiddle in a moment.

Comment: Yes, jsfiddle would be great :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fpY34/ Here's the fiddle. It's not 100% accurate, but any answers based on this should work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the markup you have, I have no clue how to do it without fixed widths, and absolute nastiness. But here's me giving my all! http://jsfiddle.net/fpY34/15/

```
<div id='outer'>
    <div id='notOuter'>
        <div id='content'>
            <div id='img'>
            </div>
            <div id='label'>
                Text example
            </div>
            <div id='closeButton'>
                X
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

and the beauty:

```
#outer { height: 30px; }
#notOuter {}
#content { float: left; position: relative; }
#closeButton { background: #0f0; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 30px; width: 30px; height: 30px;} 
#img { background: #f0f; width: 30px; height: 30px; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; }
#label { display: none; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 60px; height: 30px; background: #f00; }
#img:hover { width: 60px; z-index: 10; }
#img:hover + #label,
#label:hover { display: block; z-index: 20; }
#img:hover ~ #closeButton,
#label:hover + #closeButton { left: 60px; }
```

​

Comment: Sorry, but I can't have the close button as a sibling to the rest of the content. I added a JSFiddle as a comment to the OP.

Comment: Can I change the markup at all? It would be easier to wrap the #img and #label in a container.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's just not possible for me to change the layout. I know it'd be a _lot_ easier if I could. So, sorry but no.

Comment: That's all I have for the night. It's not pretty, but it works.

Comment: Well you're right about it not being pretty :D It looks awful, but it'll work for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

would you check this please and tell me if that what you want ?

http://jsfiddle.net/UjPtv/10/

```
<style>
        .divs
        {
            height: 20px;
            width: 100px;
            border: 1px solid;
            padding: 5px 3px;
        }
         .divs:hover
        {

            width: 50px;
            padding-left: 150px

        }
    </style>
    <div class="divs"><span>X</span></div>​
```

Comment: its only simple scenario it could be better if you need it

Comment: It doesn't quite work for me. The div expands no matter where I hover on it.

Comment: i thought this is what you want, so if you dont find the right solution, could you explain to me exactly what you want?

Comment: I want that when I hover over the div, it would expand, but if I hovered over the X (which is inside the div), it would not expand.

Comment: you need it inside the outer  div ??

Comment: Yes, I need it inside the outer div.

Comment: so can i change the whole CSS ??
dosnt Torr3nt answer works for you?

Answer (score 0):

You could float them:

```
<div class="box">
    <div>
      Content
    </div>
    <span>X</span>
</div>​​​​​​​

.box {display:inline-block;border:1px solid black}
.box div {width:100px;float:left}
.box div:hover {width:200px}
.box span {float:left}​
```

Might not work in older browsers though.